# Script for browser detection and url linking

Tags: javascript

I'm new... I'm looking for a script that detects the browser and then a function that links to a specific url based on the browser being used. I'm stuck on how to combine two functions into one js file. Using the onclick method to call one of the two functions. Does this make sense? What are my options. I know userAgent is frowned upon, what are the work arounds?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please post what you have tried so far, and explain why your code doesnt work - what happens instead of what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that can be modified very easily to include all modern browsers, this is not based on mouseover but is based on Browser detection and redirection depending on what browser.. if this is not what you are looking for please explain in more detail and either i or someone else will be able to help out better... Do you have example pages or code to work with?

```
version = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('5.') > -1) {
    version = 5
};
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('6.') > -1) {
    version = 6
};
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('7.') > -1) {
    version = 7
};
browser = 'OTHER';
if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
    browser = 'NS' + version;
}
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
    browser = 'MSIE' + version;
}
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE 3') > 0) {
    browser = 'MSIE3';
}
if (browser == 'NS5') {
    browser = 'NS6'
};
if (browser == 'MSIE3') {
    window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
}
if (browser == 'MSIE4') {
    window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
}
if (browser == 'MSIE5') {
    window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
}
if (browser == 'MSIE6') {
    window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
}
if (browser == 'MSIE7') {
    window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
}
if (browser == 'NS3') {
    window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
}
if (browser == 'NS4') {
    window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
}
if (browser == 'NS6') {
    window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
}
if (browser == 'NS7') {
    window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
}
if (browser == 'OTHER') {
    window.location = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
}
```

Thanks